# Revit-API help needed regarding FU to flow table forming for MEP calculations. New to c# and stuck

Tags: c#, revit-api

I found a piece of code by Jeremy Tammik where he manipulates what tables Revit uses in order to do its FU to flow conversions called "UserMepCalculation" on Github.

Within this piece of code he has multiple other things he manipulates that are irrelevant to my specific problem but the specific folder I am trying to modify is the "StraightSegmentCalculationServers" folder, where he populates the new FU to flow conversion table that Revit will then use.

Revit in its current state uses IPC standards for its FU to flow conversion which is insufficient to properly size piping in practice. What I am tryng to accomplish is to modify Jeremy's code to incorporate BS standards which takes diversity into account. All this means is that in order to properly calculate pipe sizes, Revit needs to use more than 1 conversion table where each table (6 in total) will be used under specific circumstances according to the maximum FU value for a specific section in a pipe system.

I have tried many different methods, but thus far have been unable to tell Revit to use a specific table for different circumstances instead of 1 table for all conversions and am a bit stuck.

As I said, I have tried many methods, but the closest I have got was the code I used below. Two system types exist in the code namely "flushtanks" and "flushvalves". I am testing my method on the "flushtanks" system. In my mind this is supposed to create the table that needs to be used before Revit uses it for the conversion. I have created a custom shared parameter that I populate the max FU value in Revit to then use as a condition in my coding to then "create" the correct table that Revit needs to use for that segment of piping. After using this method I am getting null values across the board as if Revit never does the conversion or isn't able to pull the shared parameter value in order to create the tables.

My guess as to why it is not working currently is that I do not understand in what order Revit works to do the conversion (does it pick a pipe segment at random, or does it work from one end of the system to the other? I have no idea) and thus it cannot correlate the shared parameter values with the pipe segment it's currently doing the conversion on. How does Revit decide where to start with its calculations?

It feels like something that should be simple but I am just not experienced enough with c# to know how to solve this problem at the moment and need guidance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Resources;

using Autodesk.Revit;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Plumbing;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.ExternalService;
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Creation;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using System.Data.Common;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;
using Application = Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application;
using Document = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace UserStraightSegmentCalculationServers.Pipe
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The external server that calculates the plumbing fixture flow.
    /// </summary>
    public class PlumbingFixtureFlowServer : IPipePlumbingFixtureFlowServer
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>> flushTanks = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double, double>();
        System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>> flushValves = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double, double>();

        class Global
        {
            public static List<double> MaxFU;
        }

        void Executes(UIApplication uiapp)
        {
            UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
            Application app = uiapp.Application;
            Document doc = uidoc.Document;

            var parameterValuesList = new List<double>();
            FilteredElementCollector pipes = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
            pipes.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeCurves);

            foreach (var element in pipes)
            {

                var parameter = element.LookupParameter("MaxFU");

                if (parameter != null && parameter.HasValue)
                {
                    var value = parameter.AsDouble();
                    parameterValuesList.Add(value);
                }
            }
            Global.MaxFU = parameterValuesList;
        }

        private void initilizeflushTanks()
        {                                   
         if ( flushTanks.Count > 0 )
            return;


            List<double> parameterValues = Global.MaxFU;

            //Table for MaxFU = 2
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data21 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1, 3.17);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data22 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(2, 3.17);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data23 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(3, 3.8);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data24 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(4, 4.28);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data25 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(5, 4.68);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data26 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(6, 5.07);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data27 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(7, 5.39);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data28 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(8, 5.71);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data29 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(9, 6.02);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data210 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(10, 6.26);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data211 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(11, 6.47);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data212 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(12, 6.67);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data213 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(13, 6.88);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data214 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(14, 7.09);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data215 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(15, 7.29);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data216 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(16, 7.50);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data217 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(17, 7.7);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data218 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(18, 7.91);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data219 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(19, 8.12);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data220 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(20, 8.32);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data221 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(25, 9.01);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data222 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(30, 9.71);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data223 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(35, 10.4);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data224 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(40, 11.1);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data225 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(45, 11.79);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data226 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(50, 12.48);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data227 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(60, 13.47);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data228 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(70, 14.27);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data229 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(80, 15.06);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data230 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(90, 15.85);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data231 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(100, 17.44);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data232 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(120, 18.39);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data233 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(140, 19.34);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data234 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(160, 20.29);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data235 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(180, 21.24);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data236 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(200, 22.19);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data237 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(225, 23.38);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data238 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(250, 24.57);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data239 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(275, 25.76);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data240 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(300, 26.95);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data241 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(400, 31.7);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data242 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(500, 36.46);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data243 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(750, 45.97);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data244 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1000, 55.48);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data245 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1250, 63.01);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data246 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1500, 70.53);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data247 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1750, 78.06);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data248 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(2000, 85.59);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data249 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(2500, 95.1);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data250 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(3000, 104.61);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data251 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(4000, 122.84);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data252 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(5000, 142.65);

            //Table for MaxFU = 3
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data31 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1, 4.76);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data32 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(2, 4.76);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data33 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(3, 4.76);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data34 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(4, 5.39);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data35 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(5, 5.86);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data36 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(6, 6.18);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data37 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(7, 6.5);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data38 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(8, 6.82);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data39 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(9, 7.13);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data310 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(10, 7.45);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data311 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(11, 7.67);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data312 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(12, 7.89);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data313 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(13, 8.12);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data314 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(14, 8.34);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data315 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(15, 8.56);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data316 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(16, 8.75);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data317 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(17, 8.94);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data318 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(18, 9.13);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data319 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(19, 9.32);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data320 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(20, 9.51);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data321 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(25, 10.3);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data322 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(30, 11.09);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data323 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(35, 11.73);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data324 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(40, 12.36);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data325 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(45, 12.92);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data326 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(50, 13.47);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data327 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(60, 15.06);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data328 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(70, 15.45);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data329 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(80, 16.64);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data330 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(90, 17.12);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data331 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(100, 18.23);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data332 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(120, 19.08);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data333 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(140, 19.94);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data334 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(160, 20.8);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data335 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(180, 21.65);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data336 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(200, 22.51);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data337 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(225, 23.62);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data338 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(250, 24.73);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data339 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(275, 25.84);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data340 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(300, 26.95);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data341 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(400, 31.7);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data342 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(500, 36.46);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data343 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(750, 45.97);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data344 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1000, 55.48);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data345 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1250, 63.01);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data346 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1500, 70.53);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data347 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(1750, 78.06);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data348 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(2000, 85.59);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data349 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(2500, 95.1);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data350 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(3000, 104.61);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data351 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(4000, 122.84);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> data352 = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(5000, 142.65);

            foreach (double MaxFU1 in parameterValues)
            {
                if ( MaxFU1 == 2)
                {
                    flushTanks.Add(data21);
                    flushTanks.Add(data22);
                    flushTanks.Add(data23);
                    flushTanks.Add(data24);
                    flushTanks.Add(data25);
                    flushTanks.Add(data26);
                    flushTanks.Add(data27);
                    flushTanks.Add(data28);
                    flushTanks.Add(data29);
                    flushTanks.Add(data210);
                    flushTanks.Add(data211);
                    flushTanks.Add(data212);
                    flushTanks.Add(data213);
                    flushTanks.Add(data214);
                    flushTanks.Add(data215);
                    flushTanks.Add(data216);
                    flushTanks.Add(data217);
                    flushTanks.Add(data218);
                    flushTanks.Add(data219);
                    flushTanks.Add(data220);
                    flushTanks.Add(data221);
                    flushTanks.Add(data222);
                    flushTanks.Add(data223);
                    flushTanks.Add(data224);
                    flushTanks.Add(data225);
                    flushTanks.Add(data226);
                    flushTanks.Add(data227);
                    flushTanks.Add(data228);
                    flushTanks.Add(data229);
                    flushTanks.Add(data230);
                    flushTanks.Add(data231);
                    flushTanks.Add(data232);
                    flushTanks.Add(data233);
                    flushTanks.Add(data234);
                    flushTanks.Add(data235);
                    flushTanks.Add(data236);
                    flushTanks.Add(data237);
                    flushTanks.Add(data238);
                    flushTanks.Add(data239);
                    flushTanks.Add(data240);
                    flushTanks.Add(data241);
                    flushTanks.Add(data242);
                    flushTanks.Add(data243);
                    flushTanks.Add(data244);
                    flushTanks.Add(data245);
                    flushTanks.Add(data246);
                    flushTanks.Add(data247);
                    flushTanks.Add(data248);
                    flushTanks.Add(data249);
                    flushTanks.Add(data250);
                    flushTanks.Add(data251);
                    flushTanks.Add(data252);
                }
                else if ( MaxFU1 == 3)
                {
                    flushTanks.Add(data31);
                    flushTanks.Add(data32);
                    flushTanks.Add(data33);
                    flushTanks.Add(data34);
                    flushTanks.Add(data35);
                    flushTanks.Add(data36);
                    flushTanks.Add(data37);
                    flushTanks.Add(data38);
                    flushTanks.Add(data39);
                    flushTanks.Add(data310);
                    flushTanks.Add(data311);
                    flushTanks.Add(data312);
                    flushTanks.Add(data313);
                    flushTanks.Add(data314);
                    flushTanks.Add(data315);
                    flushTanks.Add(data316);
                    flushTanks.Add(data317);
                    flushTanks.Add(data318);
                    flushTanks.Add(data319);
                    flushTanks.Add(data320);
                    flushTanks.Add(data321);
                    flushTanks.Add(data322);
                    flushTanks.Add(data323);
                    flushTanks.Add(data324);
                    flushTanks.Add(data325);
                    flushTanks.Add(data326);
                    flushTanks.Add(data327);
                    flushTanks.Add(data328);
                    flushTanks.Add(data329);
                    flushTanks.Add(data330);
                    flushTanks.Add(data331);
                    flushTanks.Add(data332);
                    flushTanks.Add(data333);
                    flushTanks.Add(data334);
                    flushTanks.Add(data335);
                    flushTanks.Add(data336);
                    flushTanks.Add(data337);
                    flushTanks.Add(data338);
                    flushTanks.Add(data339);
                    flushTanks.Add(data340);
                    flushTanks.Add(data341);
                    flushTanks.Add(data342);
                    flushTanks.Add(data343);
                    flushTanks.Add(data344);
                    flushTanks.Add(data345);
                    flushTanks.Add(data346);
                    flushTanks.Add(data347);
                    flushTanks.Add(data348);
                    flushTanks.Add(data349);
                    flushTanks.Add(data350);
                    flushTanks.Add(data351);
                    flushTanks.Add(data352);
                }

            }
        
        }
    
    private void initilizeflushValves()
    {   
      if( flushValves.Count > 0 )
        return;

      //the key is Fixture Units
      //the value is Flow (gallon (U.S.) per minute (gpm) (gal/min))
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 5, 15.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 6, 17.4 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 7, 19.8 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 8, 22.2 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 9, 24.6 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 10, 27.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 11, 27.8 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 12, 28.6 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 13, 29.4 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 14, 30.2 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 15, 31.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 16, 31.8 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 17, 32.6 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 18, 33.4 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 19, 34.2 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 20, 35.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 25, 38.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 30, 42.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 35, 44.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 40, 46.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 45, 48.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 50, 50.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 60, 54.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 70, 58.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 80, 61.2 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 90, 64.3 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 100, 67.5 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 120, 73.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 140, 77.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 160, 81.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 180, 85.5 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 200, 90.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 225, 95.5 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 250, 101.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 275, 104.5 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 300, 108.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 400, 127.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 500, 143.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 750, 177.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 1000, 208.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 1250, 239.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 1500, 269.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 1750, 297.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 2000, 325.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 2500, 380.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 3000, 433.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 4000, 525.0 ) );
      flushValves.Add( new KeyValuePair<double, double>( 5000, 593.0 ) );
    }

    private bool AlmostZero( double val )
    {
      return System.Math.Abs( val ) < double.Epsilon;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate the flow with the dimension flow (GPM - gallon (U.S.) per minute (gpm) (gal/min) ) .
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">
    /// The input for the flow calculation. The result flow is also return through the data to the caller. 
    /// </param>
    /// Return Value: Flow - the units is GPM (gallon (U.S.) per minute (gpm) (gal/min))
    private double presetFlow( double dDimensionFlow )
    {
      return dDimensionFlow;
    }
        
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate the flow with the fixture units and flow conversion mode - need to read the table(flushValves and flushTanks) .
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">
    /// The input for the flow calculation. The result flow is also return through the data to the caller. 
    /// </param>
    /// Return Value: Flow - the units is GPM (gallon (U.S.) per minute (gpm) (gal/min))
    private double getFlowFromFixtureUnits( double dFixtureUnits, FlowConversionMode eFlowConversionMode )
    {
      if( ( dFixtureUnits < 0 ) || AlmostZero( dFixtureUnits ) )
        return 0;

      initilizeflushTanks();
      initilizeflushValves();
      System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>> points = flushTanks;

      int size = flushTanks.Count;
      double dFlow = 0;

      if( eFlowConversionMode == FlowConversionMode.Valves )
      {
        points = flushValves;
        size = flushValves.Count;
      }
      else if( eFlowConversionMode == FlowConversionMode.Tanks )
      {
        points = flushTanks;
        size = flushTanks.Count;
      }
      else
      {
        return dFlow;
      }

      if( dFixtureUnits < points.ElementAt( 0 ).Key )
      {
        dFlow = points.ElementAt( 0 ).Value;
      }
      else
      {
        bool bInTable = false;
        int ii = 0;
        for( ; ii < size; ii++ )
        {
          if( dFixtureUnits <= points.ElementAt( ii ).Key )
          {
            bInTable = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        KeyValuePair<double, double> p1, p2;
        if( bInTable )
        {
          p1 = points.ElementAt( ii );
          if( ii == 0 )
            p2 = points.ElementAt( ii + 1 );
          else
            p2 = points.ElementAt( ii - 1 );
        }
        else
        {
          p1 = points.ElementAt( size - 2 );
          p2 = points.ElementAt( size - 1 );
        }

        double x1 = p1.Key;
        double y1 = p1.Value;
        double x2 = p2.Key;
        double y2 = p2.Value;
        double x = dFixtureUnits;
        double y = ( x * y2 - x1 * y2 + x2 * y1 - x * y1 ) / ( x2 - x1 );
        dFlow = y;
      }

      return dFlow;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate the flow with the input data .
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">
    /// The input for the flow calculation. The result flow is also return through the data to the caller. 
    /// </param>
    public void Calculate( PipePlumbingFixtureFlowData data )
    {
      double dResult = 0.0;

      //The flow configuration mode of the pipe: -1: invalid;  0: Preset; 1: Fixture Units
      if( data.FlowConfiguration == PipeFlowConfigurationType.Preset )
        dResult = presetFlow( data.DimensionFlow );
      else if( data.FlowConfiguration == PipeFlowConfigurationType.Demand )
        dResult = getFlowFromFixtureUnits( data.FixtureUnits, data.FlowConversionMode );

      data.Flow = dResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the method's name this server implements. 
    /// </summary>
    public string GetMethodName()
    {
      return Properties.Resources.PlumbingFixtureFlowMethodName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the Id of the server. 
    /// </summary>
    public System.Guid GetServerId()
    {
      return new Guid( "56121D7D-E1D7-42A3-BED8-F4D1D3205833" );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the Id of the service that the sever belongs to. 
    /// </summary>
    public ExternalServiceId GetServiceId()
    {
      return ExternalServices.BuiltInExternalServices.PipePlumbingFixtureFlowService;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the server's name. 
    /// </summary>
    public System.String GetName()
    {
      return Properties.Resources.PlumbingFixtureFlowServerName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the server's vendor Id. 
    /// </summary>
    public System.String GetVendorId()
    {
      return "USER";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the description of the server. 
    /// </summary>
    public System.String GetDescription()
    {
      return Properties.Resources.PlumbingFixtureFlowServerDescription;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the link of the server information. 
    /// </summary>
    public System.String GetInformationLink()
    {
      return Properties.Resources.PlumbingFixtureFlowServerInformationLink;
    }

  //  /// <summary>
  //  /// Return the server description in RTF format. 
  //  /// </summary>
  //  public System.String GetRTFDescription()
  //  {
  //    return Properties.Resources.PlumbingFixtureFlowServerDescriptionRTF;
  //  }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the server description in HTML format. 
    /// </summary>
    public System.String GetHtmlDescription()
    {
      return "HTML description of plumbing fixture flow server";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just another note to add as I didn't have enough space in my original post. Jeremy's original code references to RevitAPI.dll and RevitAPIUI.dll are outdated and should be removed and reapplied with whichever Revit version you are using (Revit 2021, 2022, 2023 etc.)

Comment: Here are some [up-to-date notes on UserMepCalculation](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2023/07/docs-lookup-mep-calculation-and-aps-devcon.html#6). Are they of any use to you?

Comment: I am not clear about your real question. Is it purely C#-related, about how to appropriately populate the two dictionaries? Does it have anything to do with Revit? Does the loading, registering and use of the external calculation server all work as expected?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately I have gone through all of those articles regarding UserMepCalculation, but they were of no use in this specific regard.

Comment: The problem is c# and Revit related. The program works completely fine when I have only one table under flush tanks as per your original code. The problem comes in when I am trying to use multiple tables under flush tanks as Revit then gives null values for everything. I am trying to use a shared parameter that I have created as an additional condition in order to choose which table under flush tanks Revit needs to use for the FU to flow conversion. For example if "MaxFU"=2 then Revit needs to use table 1, if "MaxFU"=3 then Revit needs to use table 2, etc. I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more. The shared parameter is populated onto all pipes in the system and will differ throughout depending on how the system is designed (For example, one section of the system has a Max FU of 2 whereas another section of the system has a Max FU of 8). This means that Revit needs to somehow read this shared parameter as it is converting each pipe's FU to flow to then choose the appropriate table to use for that specific pipe and not use one table for the entire system as it does in its current state.

Comment: Sorry, I do not yet understand. Can you picture Revit and your add-in as two separate black boxes and specify exactly what data exchange takes place between the two? Afaict fro you description so far, all you need to do is read and populate parameter values, nothing else. Is that correct?

Comment: Let me try and explain this then. Your original add-in gets the Fixture Unit parameter value from the pipes in Revit, matches that value to the key in your KeyValuePair list and then populates the corresponding value to the Flow parameter of the pipes in Revit. This is exactly how it should work but Revit does this for all pipes in the system. Instead I want to use a specific KeyValuePair list for different sections of the pipe system in Revit depending on a shared parameter value, which I created and populated for all pipes.

Comment: For example, if I have 2 pipes in the system where 1 of them has a shared parameter value of 1 and the other has a shared parameter value of 2 and both pipes have the same Fixture Unit value, then they should have different flow values as a result where the 1 pipe gets its flow value from 1 KeyValuePair list and the other pipe gets its flow value from a different KeyValuePair list. The first KeyValuePair list corresponds to the shared parameter value of 1 and the other corresponds to the shared parameter value of 2. So essentially yes it is just reading and populating parameter values.